# Sad Riddle - Who am I?

Tags: riddle, enigmatic-puzzle

> I Am A Time Traveler
>
> But I Almost Know, That I Feel Different Every Time
>
> I Am The First And The Last Thing From The Other Side
>
> So, No One Will Realize I Am Standing There
>
> I Thought I Was A Winner
>
> As I Looked Deeply Into Their Eyes
>
> But I Realize, It Only Happens In Wonderland

Who am I?

Answer (score 2):

Is it

> a dream

Because

> I Am A Time Traveler ->  A dream can happen at different times
>
>
> But I Almost Know, That I Feel Different Every Time - >Every dream is different each time
>
>
> I Am The First And The Last Thing From The Other Side
>
> So, No One Will Realize I Am Standing There -> Since I am the creator of the dream I am the first as well as the last and no one can know my presense
>
>
> I Thought I Was A Winner
>
> As I Looked Deeply Into Their Eyes
>
> But I Realize, It Only Happens In Wonderland    -> In the dream, I am the winner but ultimately everything is a dream or a wonderland

Comment: Nice try, but not the answer I intend :( if I am a "Dream", then I think it is not really fit in "No One Will Realize I Am Standing There" and "I Thought I Was A Winner "

Comment: You have two logic holes: (1) in the second part, a dream is not the creator of a dream. (2) in the last part you said "in a dream, I'm..." The dream is you, and it can't be inside of a dream.